# HTML5 semantic element of a playlist web app

Tags: html, element, semantic-markup

For a music web app we are creating I would like some help with the semantic structuring of all the elements involved.

A playlist consists of a title, tags and the songs.

I attached an image of how I think it should be divided. Is this correct?

< main > 
 
< header >
< h1 >Playlist title< / h1 >
< section > playlist tags < / section>
< / header >
 
< section >
 
< article > 
< h2 > song title < / h2> 
< time >today< / time > 
< menu >  add to playlist etc. < / menu > 
< / article > 
 
< article > 
< h2 > song title 2< / h2> 
< time >today< / time > 
< menu >  add to playlist etc. < / menu > 
< / article > 
 
< / section >
< / main >

[image: html5 semantic element of a playlist web app]

Should a music playlist be structured like this? Thanks for the help :).

Comment: Does `menu` even exist any more in the current version of HTML5? And `time` would refer to the time the song was added to the playlist in your approach? (I’d expect the play time of the song to be shown as well somewhere.)

Comment: And since it is a playLIST, maybe I’d actually use `ol`/`li` here rather then making an `article` out of each track … (`article` seems a little bit over-the-top for a structure that basically lists the title & a time and offers some additional controls.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn’t use a sectioning element for the playlist tags, as I don’t think they "deserve" an own entry in the document outline.

Instead of the list of the tracks only, the whole playlist including the `header` should be in a sectioning element. If you think the playlist is content that can stand on its own (e.g., a curated playlist), `article` might be appropriate, otherwise `section`.

The markup for a single track looks fine, apart from the `menu` element, which is no longer part of HTML5 (it’s [still in HTML 5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html51-20140617/interactive-elements.html#the-menu-element)). And you are not using the `time` element correctly, as "today" is not a valid value.

You might want to use a list, but it’s not really needed, so it can be omitted.

```
<main>

   <article>

     <header>
       <h1>Playlist title</h1>
       <div>playlist tags</div>
     </header>

     <ul>
       <li><article><!-- track 1 --></article></li>
       <li><article><!-- track 2 --></article></li>
     </ul>

   </article>

</main>
```

If you want to semantically annotate your content with Microdata and/or RDFa, have a look at Schema.org’s [`MusicPlaylist` type](http://schema.org/MusicPlaylist).

Comment: Thanks, Makes sense! One question though. I understand a playlist is technically a list but I don't understand the advantage of putting things in an ul or ol. I always have to add extra css to remove the padding and the list style type. What are the advantages?

Comment: @MikelPorrasHoogland: Mostly a semantic question (one could argue that you should always use the most-specific elements available). One advantage might be that tools like screen readers can offer special list navigation and announcements like "List, item 1 of 13" or similar.